# Use Java Libraries in Scala?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scala

I have question I hope somebody guide me
Can I use All Java Libraries such as Guava, Gson, Log4j, Spring, Hibernate & etc in Scala ???
for example can i convert below code to scala ?? (GUAVA library)

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
public class mainJ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fantasyGenres = {"Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion"};        
        String joined = Joiner.on(',').join(fantasyGenres);
        System.out.print(joined);
    }
}
```

I want choose SCALA as main programming language but i dont know Can I use Java libraries without limitation in scala or not ?
Can anyone convert above code in scala ?
thanks

Comment: `Can I use Java libraries without limitation in scala or not?` yes you can. `Can anyone convert above code in scala?` yes, I guess even you can with a little effort. See [Java to Scala cheatsheet](http://techblog.realestate.com.au/java-to-scala-cheatsheet/) or [A Scala Tutorial for Java Programmers](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html).

Comment: You can use Java libraries, but that doesn't mean you should when you can avoid it.

Comment: In general, yes, you can use ANY Java lib in Scala. You will also see that Scala offers you plenty of functionality out of the box. For a small example, your join above would be: `val fantasyGenres = Array("Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion"); val joined = fantasyGenres.mkString(",")`  without using any external library.

Comment: @maasg  / The main point in the code is the Guava library
In fact, I want to use this library in Scala
Please write the equivalent code in Scala by Guava Library

Comment: When working in Java I'm a fervent user of Guava but I have not found any use for it in Scala. If you *really* want to use guava, you could do: `val fantasyGenres = Array("Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion"); val joined = Joiner.on(',').join(fantasyGenres); println(joined)`

Comment: must use "join(fantasyGenres.iterator.asJava)" as Dmitry Kuskov answer my problem was exactly here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others pointed out, you can easily use Java classes in Scala. Gyro Gearless and maasg showed how can you use Scala's library to do Guava's work in your sample. You can use Guava as well obviously, here's how you can transform you sample to Scala more straightforwardly:

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object MainJ extends App {
  val fantasyGeneres = Array("Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion")
  val joined = Joiner.on(',').join(fantasyGeneres.toIterable.asJava)
  println(joined)
}
```

Note that I used `JavaConverters` to convert Scala's `Iterable` to Java's version, but that's the only thing that can be considered as inconvenience here.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Scala FAQ](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4.html#4n267) (emphasis added):

> The standard Scala backend is a Java VM. Scala classes are Java
>   classes, and vice versa. **You can call the methods of either language
>   from methods in the other one**. You can extend Java classes in Scala,
>   and vice versa. The main limitation is that some Scala features do not
>   have equivalents in Java, for example traits.
>
> Do I need to convert Java data structures to Scala, and vice versa?
>
> You do not have to convert Java data structures at all for using them
>   in Scala. You can use them "as is". For instance, Scala classes can
>   subclass Java classes, you can instantiate Java classes in Scala, you
>   can access methods, fields (even if they are static), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may transparently use Java classes in Scala. But very often there is an idiomatic way to express things more elegantly in Scala. For your given example this might be:

```
c:\opt>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val fantasyGenres = List("Space Opera", "Horror", "Magic realism", "Religion")
fantasyGenres: List[String] = List(Space Opera, Horror, Magic realism, Religion)

scala> val joined = fantasyGenres.mkString(",")
joined: String = Space Opera,Horror,Magic realism,Religion
```